# Deployment of a Browser Helper Object

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, deployment, add-on

I wrote an IE Plugin with the .NET SpicIE Framework.

During development I tested it with the following commands:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm" "plugin.dll"
"C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil" /if "plugin.dll"

Now I want to create an MSI Installer with the Microsoft WiX Toolkit.

But I don´t know which Registry Entrys are Required. I record all the entries written from regasm but it isn´t working because the plugin.dll have to be in the global assembly cache. Some folder like C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\plugin\1.0.0.0__ec146fd6848c0024

any ideas how to install an IE BHO?

---

now I do it without the SpicIE framework. I followd this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx?fid=447248&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51&select=2421069

If I register the dll with regasm /codebase it works.

If I want to install it with an msi-installer (WiX toolset) it dont work :(
I unregister the dll, search the registry for my GUID -> I clean all out from the registry. After that I make a snapshot from the registry, run the regasm command and make a second snapshot. Then I compared the snapshots and create a wix-file witch inserts all the added registry keys. It dont work. I cant make it run via the installer...

any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, you probably shouldn't be using SpicIE for anything other than prototyping and demos. Browser extensions based on the .NET Framework incur reliability and performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

To second EricLaw's comment, SpicIE is not meant for production use (see the disclaimer I added on the code.msdn.com page).  Load times are abysmal (you'll notice it takes up to 4 seconds sometimes to spin up the necessary libraries), and the whole project was designed to be for proof-of-concepts.

If you *need* to use .NET for BHO construction in a production environment, there are some good, lightweight examples on The Code Project (codeproject.com) that can get you started.  Otherwise, Code Project, as well as MSDN, offer some good C++ examples.

Feel free to contact me (alias below + @microsoft.com) if you have detailed questions.

Thanks!
mattcrow [msft]

Answer (score 0):

Here is [information and examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/06/21/3450539.aspx) of how to install assemblies in the GAC with WiX.  Also, here's a great [WiX tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/).